# Migrate from getSharedPreferences(custom file) to getDefaultSharedPreferences()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I originally wrote and published my app, I was using a custom written activity to handle application settings. I used custom file name to store shared preferfences, like this:

```
getSharedPreferences("custom_settings_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But now I'm refactoring my app and I would like to implement `PreferenceActivity` or [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) and an xml file with `PreferenceScreen` section. Every tutorial or example that I've seen is using

```
getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

to retrieve shared preferences, because PreferenceActivity assumes default filename to store preferences and there's no way to tell it to use a different one(at least I couldn't find one after an hour of searching and reading documentation).

So now I have a problem. If I just simply use the new default file, existing users of my app will lose their settings when they update the app, because the new application will not know anything about "custom_settings_file". What would be the best way to move the data from an old file to a new one on app update?

Here are the possible options that I could come up with:

- Extend `Application` class and implement a piece of code in onCreate() so that every time my app is launched, it would check for existence of "custom_settings_file" and move it's contents to the new one. But running a block of code on every app launch seems like wasting too much processing resources for an operation that only needs to run once.
- Just notify the user that their old settings are gone. But obviously this is not acceptable.

Is there a better solution, than option 1? Perhaps someone has already faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is preventing you from doing number 1 only once?
Just add a "migration" boolean to the new sharedpreferences.

Comment: That's an elegant solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you also load the xml preference file then you can try this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, R.xml.preference_file, false);
```

If not (you want to add each preference item dynamically in your code) then you can do like this:

```
PreferenceManager pm = getPreferenceManager();
pm.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_PRIVATE);
pm.setSharedPreferencesName(YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME);
```

In case you still want to use the `defaultSharedPreference` and process the migration then ... I'm writing this and I see Nicklas's answer, so I'm done here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add value in your new SharedPreferences that records whether you are a new install or an upgrade. If you don't have the setting in your sharedpreferences, check to see if you have an old preferences file in the way you were before. Then convert those preferences to your new method, and set your private setting indicating that it's been upgraded. Then just set the new value indicating the new state and you won't need to check your old preferences any more.